# Document not displaying latest changes in Sharepoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, office-web-apps, office

#### The problem

A user is working in a `Sharepoint Library` with a `.ppt` file that has been changed recently.

If she opens the document with `Sharepoint Online's Power Point`, she is able to see the last version.
If she tries to open it with the installed `Office 2016's Power Point`, she can only see an **outdated version** of the file.

We've also tried copying the link from the file, and opening the file from the PowerPoint client's top bar menu.

#### More info

- The original creator of this file also claims that he's suffering the same issues.
- It doesn't happen only with that file.
- Internet temporals and cache have been cleared.
- The entire Office has been uninstalled and installed again.
- Office package has been repaired.
- She's using Windows 10 with Office 2016.
- Her laptop is brand new (4 months) and have had no issues with the Office client until now.
- File history is on.
- We are using Sharepoint 2016.

Our IT support team claims that the issue is not on the client, but on Sharepoint.
My team has been talking to IT guys and we don't see any problem with the file or with the current Sharepoint site.

We've checked with the user that the problem is real and she's opening like the version 15 from 30, being 30 the last version.

The users refuse to collaborate reinstalling more software at this point.

We believe that we may be missing something in our Library or site config...

Have you guys encountered an issue like this?

Comment: Are you using SharePoint 2016 or SharePoint Online? Also are you using Office 2016 or Office 365 Pro Plus.

Comment: SharePoint 2016. But it has a tool to open documents in the web browser called SharePoint Online. The client is using Office 2016.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this happen quite often.

I don't know if you are aware, or tried this already, but Office caches documents in the 'Upload Center'.

As soon as you open a document, it will store a copy in the local machine, and it this causes problems very often, such as the ones you describe.

I can't guarantee that this is *the* fix for your issue, but you can give it a try.

1. go to start, and type 'Upload'
2. fire up 'Office 2016 Upload Center'
3. go to settings > delete cached files

[image]

Other suggestions:

- clear cache at %userProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.mso
- convert old office formats (.ppt) to the new format (.pptx) to fully support all features and avoid issues
- look for Office hotfixes that possibly address your issue
- plan for an optimal configuration of the upload center cache. maybe delete cache on close, or reduce the amount of days, or both

Comment: As I thought, the problem has to be client side. We could not solve this yet but we've been trying to get in contact with the user mixing yours and Asad Refai's answers. Hopefully I would get this issue fixed. Thanks.

Comment: good luck! for me the key is "If she opens the document with Sharepoint Online's Power Point, she is able to see the last version.". we have lots of problems with the office client, which is either caused by KB2920679, or by some office crash, which usually helps by reinstalling office. but we are on 2013, so you might need to look for an office patch for your scenario. e.g. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/office-updates-msi

Comment: Upload Center fix worked... she had a file stuck there. She had to bring the last version from there and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried seeing the version activities from the Activity Icon. Refer below it lists out all versions. And you choose to open the latest one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Office file cache need to be cleaned, so I deleted content in the following folder:

C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache
After deleting it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint stores documents with a different timestamp in the local cache and on the server. So even though the documents are actually the same version, Sharepoints keeps annoying you with the message that there is a "newer" version available. It's one of the myriad of bugs in Office 365 and Sharepoint that is known for years, but which Microsoft just refuses to correct. In the end they are not in the business of creating properly working software.